# REST API 404 error: "Request does not match any route error" at Shipping method selection Magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, rest-api

The REST API request **rest/default/V1/guest-carts/:cartId/shipping-information** is returning a 404 error with message "Request does not match any route".

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure you are making an API request call with **POST** method.
And it should be:

> **rest/V1/guest-carts/:cartId/shipping-information**

Comment: but how I can update the core API can you please explain more

Comment: you can make your own API endpoint instead